# jquery load tab-content onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, tabs

These are chrome-like tabs. In this when i click on first tab i.e. facebook tab it shows facebook content and when i click on second tab i.e. on twitter tab it shows first tab's content and while clicking on third fourth and fifth tabs it shows their own content, there is no noissue with third fourth and fifth tabs. 
And when clicking second time on first tab it shows no content. same is the issue with second tab.

**HTML**

```
    <div class="box box-primary">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="tabs">
                    <div class="tab fb-icon-color active" id="#tab1">
                     <a href="#tab1">
                        <div class="tab-box">
                            <h3 style="text-align: center;margin-top: 15px;" class="facebook">
                                <i class="fa fa-facebook" title="Facebook"></i>
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab twitter-icon-color">
                        <a href="#tab2">
                        <div class="tab-box">
                            <h3 style="text-align: center;margin-top: 15px;"><i class="fa fa-twitter" title="Twitter"></i></h3>
                        </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab google-plus-icon-color">
                        <a href="#tab3">
                        <div class="tab-box">
                            <h3 style="text-align: center;margin-top: 15px;"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" title="Google+"></i></h3>
                        </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab crawl-icon-color">
                        <a href="#tab4">
                        <div class="tab-box">
                            <h3 style="text-align: center;margin-top: 15px;"><i class="fa fa-bug" aria-hidden="true" title="Crawling"></i>
                        </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab video-icon-color">
                        <a href="#tab5">
                        <div class="tab-box">
                            <h3 style="text-align: center;margin-top: 15px;"><i class="fa fa-video-camera" title="Youtube"></i></h3>
                        </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>  
                <div class="tabs-content pane">
                    <!-- first Pane -->
                <div id="tab1" >
                    <%= render :partial =>"fb_tab"%>
                </div>
                <div id="tab2" style="display: none;">
                    <%= render :partial =>"twitter_tab"%>
                </div>
                <div id="tab3" style="display: none;">
                    <%= render :partial =>"gplus_tab"%>
                </div>
                <div id="tab4" style="display: none;">
                    <%= render :partial =>"crawled_tab"%>
                </div>
                <div id="tab5" style="display: none;">
                    <h1> youtube</h1>
                </div>
                </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>

 $(document).ready(function (){
 $('.tab').click(function(){
  $('.tab').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $(".tabs a").click(function() {
        $(".pane div").hide();
        $($(this).attr("href")).show();
    });
});

    });
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
.tabs {
  height:45px;
  padding: 1px 0 0 0;
  overflow:visible;
}
.tab {
  width:246px;
  height:45px;
  overflow:hidden;
  float:left;
  margin:0 -15px 0 0;
}


.tab-box {
  height:50px;
  background: rgba(60, 141, 188, 0.87);
  border-radius: 4px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  margin:0 13px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px  #fff inset;
 -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(30deg);
 -moz-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(30deg);

}

.tab.active {
  z-index:40;
  position:relative;
  padding-bottom:1px;
}
.tab.active .tab-box{
  background-color: #ECF0F5;
  @include background-image(linear-gradient(top, #ccc , #ddd 3%, rgba(#eee, 0.5)  ));
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 #fff inset;
}

.tabs-content.pane {
  z-index:1;
  padding:15px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  background:#ECF0F5;  
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the click function is working next time. to avoid all the complexity use bootstap tab ..

Comment: yeah there is no issue with third fourth and fifth tab. when i click first time on first tab it show its own content and when i click on second tab it shows first tab's content. and while clicking second time on first tab it show blank i.e. no content and on clicking second time on second tab it also shows blank.

Comment: and yeah i can use bootstrap tab but i want to use this one. And there is issue with javascript active class i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have nested click handlers, please try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $(".tabs a").click(function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         $('.tab').removeClass('active');
         $(this).parent().addClass('active');
         $(".pane div").hide();
         $($(this).attr("href")).show();
     });
 });
```

Comment: Now when i am clicking on second tab it shows no content blank

Comment: And when i click second time on first tab and second tab it shows blank i.e. no content

Comment: No its not working :(  with this tab is not getting active

Comment: That's what `$(this).parent().addClass('active');` do ! this is weird ! have you copied the last edit ?

Comment: Ismail answer is correct i think. Have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/link2pk/Lf8680v0/1/ 
your <%= render :partial =>"text"%> values might not be rendering properly